# What are those visual and auditory reflex controlled by the midbrain?

Tags: physiology, brain, vision, brain-stem

The midbrain is a centre for certain visual and auditory reflexes. But what are those reflexes exactly? My study book says that these reflexes are, e.g., responsible for moving the eyes to view something as the head turns. But I don't quite get it. What is the difference between those reflexes controlled by the midbrain and those mediated by the spinal cord?

Comment: You probably reading about [Vestibulo–ocular reflex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibulo%E2%80%93ocular_reflex). This is one that allows your eyes to follow object of interest even though your head rotates.  I see difference as that spinal cord controls motor neurons of limbs, not controlling muscles of the eye.

Comment: Where are you after exactly? Are you after the different *types of auditory/visual reflexes* mediated by the midbrain? Are you after startle responses? Or after eye movements? I think you need to add a little bit more detail, as *I don't quite get "it"* is quite vague. Also, the concluding sentence does not really match your question title. Are you interested in the difference between spinal-chord-mediated reflexes in particular? That is again quite broad, as the spinal chord covers the entire body including many receptors (pain, heat...)